# Presenting an array of objects in a tableview controller from user defaults

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

I've been having trouble presenting data from objects in an array stored in user defaults. To store the object in user defaults, I encode the object in json and when I need to read it I decode the object. The table view controller in my app successfully displays the entire array in my app, however, when I relaunch the app to make sure it will read from user defaults again, only the most recent addition to the array is displaying in the table view controller. This is most likely because of the encodeArray.removeAll(). When I remove the "removeAll()" function call, duplicates of each object are displayed in the table view only to present correctly if I relaunch the app. Any help would be appreciated!

This is the view controller containing the tableview controller. When a separate VC adds to the array of objects, it sends a post notification to return, load the array, and reload the data.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(returnToVC(_:)), name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "returnToVC"), object: nil)

        goalLoadService.instance.loadGoals()
        tableView.reloadData()
        self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = self.view.frame.size.width - 80
    }
    
    @objc func returnToVC(_ notification: Notification) {
        goalLoadService.instance.loadGoals()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
   
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return goalLoadService.instance.goals.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "goalCell", for: indexPath) as? GoalCell {
            let goal = goalLoadService.instance.goals[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureCell(goal: goal)
            return cell
        } else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }
```

This is the IBAction that is called in the second VC when the user adds to the array. The object is then encoded into JSON and stored in user defaults. Before it dismisses, a post notification is made.

```
@IBAction func onBeginTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if let duration: Int = Int(goalDurationTxt.text!){
            let goalObject = GoalDataModel(goalTitle: goalNameTxt.text!, goalDuration: duration)
            goalLoadService.instance.encodeJSON(goalObject: goalObject)
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "returnToVC"), object: nil)
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

This is the service that encodes and decodes the objects from user defaults. 'decodeJSON' is called within loadGoals() when reading from user defaults and 'encodeJSON' is called when writing to user defaults. For reference, the GoalDataModel is a codable struct with a string title attribute and an integer (duration) attribute.

Also, in a separate file, a constant is defined for user defaults.

```
let DEFAULTS = UserDefaults.standard
```

```
class goalLoadService {
    
    static let instance = goalLoadService()
    
    var encodeArray: [Data] = DEFAULTS.array(forKey: "goalArray") as? [Data] ?? []
    
    
    var goals: [GoalDataModel] = [GoalDataModel]()
    
    
    func loadGoals(){
        guard let array = DEFAULTS.array(forKey: "goalArray") else {
            return
        }
        
        decodeJSON(array: array as! [Data])
    }
    
    func encodeJSON(goalObject: GoalDataModel) {
        
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        
        guard let encoded = try? encoder.encode(goalObject) else {
            return
        }
        encodeArray.removeAll()
        encodeArray.append(encoded)
        DEFAULTS.removeObject(forKey: "goalArray") 
        DEFAULTS.set(encodeArray, forKey: "goalArray")
    }
    
    
    func decodeJSON(array: [Data]){
        for goalData in array {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            if let loadedGoal = try? decoder.decode(GoalDataModel.self, from: goalData) {
                goals.append(loadedGoal)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `decodeJSON` function, you are adding the decoded values to the existing `goals` array which is the reason for duplicates. So reset the goals array in `loadGoals` function and you won't have to use `encodeArray.removeAll()` whenever you are adding a new item.

```
func loadGoals(){
    guard let array = DEFAULTS.array(forKey: "goalArray") else {
        return
    }
    goals = []
    decodeJSON(array: array as! [Data])
}
```